# Ruby - Rails - Pass text to javascript

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why isn't this passing text to javascript/jquery.? `@i[:error]` definitely has a string in it, I can print that on console.

js.erb file -

```
<% if @i[:error] != "" %>
<% puts "--> " + @i[:error]  %>
#--> error
#Validation error(s):
#-  Item Is not defined or blank. # that's the error string in @i[:error]

$(function() {
$("#error_message").attr("class", "message_error");
$('#error').text("<%= @i[:error]%>"); #Not working for @i[:error]
#$('#error').text("<%= "#{@i[:error]}"%>");#Not working for @i[:error]

#$('#error').text("Test"); #This is working
#$('#error').text("<%= "?????"%>"); #This is working
});
<% else %>
........#fine here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's probably because of the line break. You can fix it by using [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript).

> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript
>   segments.

So:

```
$('#error').text("<%= escape_javascript(@i[:error]) %>");
```

Comment: Yep, that is what it was. line break was causing the issue. You solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify what debugger says it would be easier to understand the problem. This code for erb views works fine:

```
<% @i = {} %>
<% @i[:error] = "Error" %>  

<% unless @i[:error].blank? %>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#error').text('<%= @i[:error] %>'); // Works fine
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Pay attention that emptiness of string is checked by **blank?** method, I think it look much nicer than using **!=** operator.

Comment: Don't know what is wrong there. I tried your change but no luck.

Comment: Can this be because of line break in the string that javascript cannot accept?